# query first number of items after an id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

i am thinking of implementing a cursor based pagination and I think of encoding and decoding an id. is it possible to query like this in mongoose?

```
MyModel.find({ _id: 4 }).limit(10)
```

so basically after that id, you query for the next 10 items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it using

### skip & limit

For Eg:

```
MyModel.find({ _id: 4 }).skip(0).limit(10)

MyModel.find({ _id: 4 }).skip(10).limit(10)
```

You can keep increasing the skip value by 10 and your pagination is done!

Read more: https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/mongodb-skip-limit.php